# Get the Likes of a retweet with tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

So I just started using tweepy and I want to know, is there a way to get the likes of the tweet that was retweeted? Currently, I am storing the tweets inside of a dataframe, but when tweepy gets a retweet the favorite_count method returns 0 because you are not able to like a retweet. What I am wondering is if there is a way to track the original tweets likes, retweets, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; tweet.retweeted_status.favorite_count

The reason you cannot obtain the likes of the tweet that was retweeted is because of the way that the Tweepy API is set up. Consider this from the Tweepy Documentation.

> When using extended mode with a Retweet, the full_text attribute of the Status object may be truncated with an ellipsis character instead of containing the full text of the Retweet. However, since the retweeted_status attribute (of a Status object that is a Retweet) is itself a Status object, the full_text attribute of the Retweeted Status object can be used instead.